# Do I need to format a new SSD?

Tags: ssd

I've read that it is necessary to secure erase an SSD when purchased. Is that true or can I simply install Win 7 64bit on it without any concerns? Are SSDs from Toshiba differently handled than others?

Comment: Forget a format when dealing with SSD, just encrypt the contents, before ANY data is placed on it.  If unencrypted data is placed on it, it basically is there forever, until its replaced ( eventually ).

Comment: Or until you used it enough and you overwrite the old data content. One suggestion I heard from a podcast called Security Now (to add to @Ramhound comment) is if you already have unencrypted data, and are worried about the data getting recovered, start using full disk encryption (truecrypt for example) and keep using the disk. Eventually the encrypted data will write over the un-encrypted data and your un-encrypted data will no longer be recoverable.

Comment: @Darius - I listen to `Security Now` and while everything you say is true, that leaves a great deal up to the actual controller, encrypting your drive before any data is placed on it and using a secure wipe feature is always best.

Comment: @Ramhound I understand. The suggestion is when you already have unencrypted data in the HDD, and don't want to secure wipe the SSD (don't want to spend the time). Going through the suggestion from Steve is a good workaround to ensure the data eventually will get encrypted, and you have no time loss to do the secure wipe and re-installation from scratch. But thank you for the input.

Answer (score 1):

You asked different things in your title and message body.

If unformatted, or pre-formatted in a different filesystem than you'll be using, you need to format, of course.

When purchased, there is no reason to run a secure erase. Before disposal, yes. [And there may be some issues with being absolutely sure it's wiped clean](http://www.kingston.com/us/community/articledetail?ArticleId=10) - though the usual hammer as employed by organizations that really don't want people sifting through their old data will probably still work, if employed sufficiently.